# Best approach to keep external system consistent (in sync) with database?

Tags: spring-boot, rest, architecture, message-queue, software-design

I have created a Rest service using Spring boot and I would like some suggestions on how to keep the database and external system state in sync. The endpoint creates a cloud function (external system) and then stores the relevant entity in a relational database. Assuming, I can validate the creation of the cloud function  before writing to the database, there are two scenarios which may lead to inconsistencies:

1. Cloud function is created but the database is offline and cannot be written to.
2. Cloud function is created and the service crashes before writing to the database.

The issue of consistency could be solved using a message-broker like RabbitMQ, whereby the method used to create the cloud function is idempotent, such that if any part of the process fails the message would not be marked as "completed". After a small number of failed attempts, the message would be passed to an error queue for investigation.

I would like some thought on whether this is a valid approach or simply adding unnecessary complexity to the system and if there is a more straightforward way to solve this issue?

Cheers